# rDrop dropbox api non-expiring tokens/seamless token issues

Tags: r, token, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using the `rDrop` package that is available from https://github.com/karthikram/rDrop, and after a bit of tweaking (as all the functions don't quite work as you would always expect them to) I have got it to work finally in the way I would like, but it still requires authorisation verification to allow the use of the app, once you get the token each time, as I think that tokens expire over time...(if this is not the case and I can hard code in my token please tell me as that would be a good solution too...)

Basically I wanted a near seamless way of downloading csv files from my dropbox folders from the commandline in R in one line of code so that I dont need to click on the allow button after the token request.

Is this possible?

Here is the code I used to wrap up a dropbox csv download.

```
db.csv.download <- function(dropbox.path, ...){

cKey <- getOption('DropboxKey')
cSecret <- getOption('DropboxSecret')
reqURL <- "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token"
authURL <- "https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth/authorize"
accessURL <- "https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/access_token/"

require(devtools)
install_github("ROAuth", "ropensci")
install_github("rDrop", "karthikram")
require(rDrop)
dropbox_oa <- oauth(cKey, cSecret, reqURL, authURL, accessURL, obj = new("DropboxCredentials"))
cred <- handshake(dropbox_oa, post = TRUE)
raw.data <- dropbox_get(cred,dropbox.path)
data <- read.csv(textConnection(raw.data), ...)
data
}
```

Oh and if its not obvious I have put my dropbox key and secret in my .Rprofile file, which is what the getOption part is referring to.

Thanks in advance for any help that is provided. (For bonus points...if anybody knows how to get rid of all the loading messages even for the install that would be great...)

Comment: Something worth noting: Dropbox API access tokens don't expire for a very long period of time, effectively never, so you can get the access token once, and store and reuse it for all future calls. Access tokens can be revoked via https://www.dropbox.com/account/applications though.

Comment: Any idea what that timeframe is out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm the author of the package. Please file any issues [here](https://github.com/karthikram/rDrop/issues/new). @Greg is right, tokens never expire unless user revokes it from the Dropbox web settings. I state in my README that you can store the tokens to disk and load as needed.

Comment: @Maiasaura How you know about this? Is somewhere documented expiration time of Dropbox token or this is just your estimation based on practical projects and experience. Thanks ;)

Comment: It's in the Dropbox documentation and generally true of most token (except for ones that are set to expire every 24 hours). See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-token

Answer (score 1):

```
library(rDrop) 
# my keys are in my .rprofile, otherwise specifiy inline
db_token <- dropbox_auth()
# Hit ok to authorize once through the browser and hit enter back at the R prompt.
save(db_token, file="my_dropbox_token.rdata")
```

Dropbox token are non-expiring and can be revoked anytime from the [Dropbox web panel](https://www2.dropbox.com/account#applications).

For future use:

```
library(rDrop)
load('~/Desktop/my_dropbox_token.rdata')
df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=rnorm(10))
> df
    x          y
1   1 -0.6135835
2   2  0.3624928
3   3  0.5138807
4   4 -0.2824156
5   5  0.9230591
6   6  0.6759700
7   7 -1.9744624
8   8 -1.2061920
9   9  0.9481213
10 10 -0.5997218
dropbox_save(db_token, list(df), file="foo", ext=".rda")
rm(df)
df2 <- db.read.csv(db_token, file='foo.rda')
> df2
    x          y
1   1 -0.6135835
2   2  0.3624928
3   3  0.5138807
4   4 -0.2824156
5   5  0.9230591
6   6  0.6759700
7   7 -1.9744624
8   8 -1.2061920
9   9  0.9481213
10 10 -0.5997218
```

If you have additional problems, please file an [issue](https://github.com/karthikram/rDrop/issues/new).

Comment: I am open to suggestions and improvements so please file those as issues or submit pull requests. thx.